# How to communicate with about 1 km range?

Tags: multirotor, antenna, long-range-drone, radio-frequency

How can I set up a communication link between some drones that can be 1 km away from each other? The communication should be done by broadcast (Ad Hoc) and not point to point. What type of transmitter/receiver should I use? The transmission bit rate is about 100 bytes per second.

Comment: Probably looking for something in the 915MHz or 433MHz depending on your region. Search for LoRa radios

Comment: Hi Jenifer, may I ask you your Contry and if you are working on a cooperating drone project, since I am developing something similar thanks, Happy to support